# Nvidia Graphics card and driver installation

Tags: terminal, gpu, nvidia

I have buit an egpu for my Mac and read several articles about correct driver installation and booting. These articles suggest to disable SIP in terminal (which I have done and it works fine). However, I don't understand what this process does and what SIP is.

Answer (score 0):

**SIP** refers to **System Integrity Protection**. It is detailed in [this](https://support.apple.com/en-in/ht204899) Apple Support document. I presume you have read about one of the eGPU workarounds (scripts) that require SIP to be disabled. This is to allow the script(s) to modify system files.

SIP can be managed using the `csrutil` command line tool. For example, to disable SIP, `csrutil disable` will disable SIP completely. Note that SIP can be managed only in privileged environments such as macOS Recovery's Terminal.

SIP may also be partially disabled if needed. Example use case: If one needs to provide some **boot-args** using `nvram`, NVRAM protections need to be disabled using `csrutil` (this protection was introduced in macOS Sierra).